# mat-auto-comlete selected value

Tags: selected, mat-autocomplete

```
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
   <mat-label>Adjustment nominal account</mat-label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Adjustment nominal account" aria-label="Number" matInput
   [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="nominal" [(value)]="selectedVal">
   <mat-autocomplete #nominal="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option"> {{option}} </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>
```

Please Help me:

how how to add default selected value in mat-auto-complete?